# Programmatically restart IIS7 (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, iis-7

Is it possible to restart IIS7 using C#? If so, how?

Comment: I'm curious, why do you want this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\windows\system32\iisreset.exe");
```

should do the trick :)

Dan

Comment: Probably should use environment variable for windows path though :)

Comment: If i have a list of servers i want to execute how can i do that

Answer (score 2):

Just execute the command-line option using `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start();`