# How to Restart MVC4 project Programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need to restart my mvc4 web application programmatically. But [System.Web.HttpRuntime.UnloadAppDomain()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.unloadappdomain%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) doesn't work.

What is the best way to restart asp.net mvc application? Please mind that changing web.config content or folder names doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Why doesn't `System.Web.HttpRuntime.UnloadAppDomain()` work for you?

Comment: By restarting the website in IIS. Are you looking to do this from within your MVC application? Can I further ask why you must restart the application?

Comment: I'm using an output cache like that [CustomOutputCache(DurationApplicationKey = "cacheSql", Location = OutputCacheLocation.Server)], So when database has been changed from admin panel, app will be restarted and values will be taken.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, I don't know, but My admin panel is classic asp.net and user interface is mvc4. Also you can check this link: http://daron.yondem.com/en/post/d82b6b05-8c59-4136-becd-329156083b75

Answer (score 12):

this code work for me. just call it to reload application.

```
System.Web.HttpRuntime.UnloadAppDomain();
```

[More info](http://daron.yondem.com/software/post/d82b6b05-8c59-4136-becd-329156083b75)

> This method will just unload our application. If you just put this method in an ASP.NET web button you are totally done. So when will our application reloaded? Actually if you click your button it will first launch our method and unload application. Further on the web page we are on at that moment will be reloaded as well, because we just clicked a button and the web page should refresh. After launching our method the page refresh process will cause our application to reload as well.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT - After looking at comment on OutputCache in the question**, You can invalidate OutputCache programmatically, [Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565239/any-way-to-clear-flush-remove-outputcache)

If still you want to Restart IIS or AppPool then you can follow these resources -

- [Programmatically start/Stop a Website in IIS](http://adamprescott.net/2011/09/26/programmatically-start-stop-iis-web-sites-in-c/)
- [Restart IIS7 in C# using iisreset.exe and
  System.Diagnostics.Process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315654/programmatically-restart-iis7-c)
- [Recycle ApplicationPool for IIS in C#](http://www.logue.com.ar/blog/2008/02/find-and-recycle-current-application-pool-programmatically-for-iis-6/)

Comment: Restart the full IIS with 400 sites, just to restart one site ? Even better idea, reboot.